# I encountered another error trying to install my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Installing template dependencies using npm... npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '... PGP SIGNATURE-----\r' npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\Madu Emmanuel IP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-10-14T17_25_58_364Z-debug.log `npm install --save @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2` failed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

Try:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

When you get errors such as the one above, clearing the cache can often help.